# How to apply borderWidth to data items in Heatmap using Echarts?

Tags: heatmap, echarts

Is there a way to apply border width around data items in heat map Echarts?

I'm trying to create a table like chart with colours applied to each cell based on some condition. like below

[image]

Looks like I can use heatmap solution as in below, but I need to apply some border width around the data items. Currently they are all clubbed together.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian

[image]
I have gone through the Echarts documentation but haven't found any option to apply borderWidth or some padding around data items.

Any suggestions on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set border width with styles:

```js
itemStyle: {
  borderWidth: 3
}
```

Docs: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-heatmap.itemStyle.borderWidth

Comment: Sorry, I'm on the road and cannot test it from mobile phone.

Comment: Yes, it works. Looks like I just overlooked this option, but is there any option to apply border width to empty items as well? so that we can have consistent line gaps? I tried spiltLine both on xAxis & yAxis combined with borderWidth and it works for the most of the part but when there are too many items on xAxis or yAxis, It doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: I'm on vacation and still don't have my laptop at hand for test and my answer can be wrong. You can try the option with set to empty cells zero value and stylize as empty cells by visualMap. It may be not quite easy but this is the first thing that comes to mind. If not success then I'll can try to find solution on the first working days after this holidays.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Sergey's answer, here's a detailed alternative:

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'Heatmap',
    type: 'heatmap',
    data: data,
    label: {
      show: false
  },

  itemStyle: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderType: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#ffffff'
  },
```